# Refactor the existing code :- put a portion of a code in a method and use that method

Tags: java

The existing **fillModel** method is as below

```
@Override
        protected void fillModel(final Model model,
                final List<FacebookChannelConfig> items) {
            final Map<FacebookChannelConfig, Boolean> defaultConfigMap = Maps
                    .newHashMapWithExpectedSize(items.size());
            for (FacebookChannelConfig channelConfig : items) {
                if (configRepository.getDefault() != null
                        && configRepository.getDefault().getId().toString()
                                .equals(channelConfig.getId().toString())) {
                    defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, Boolean.TRUE);
                } else {
                    defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, Boolean.FALSE);
                }
                if (channelConfig.getOwner().getId().getId() != userContext
                        .getOrganization().getId().getId()) {
                    channelConfig.setName(channelConfig.getName() + "("
                            + channelConfig.getOwner().getName() + ")");
                }
            }
            model.addAttribute("isDefault", defaultConfigMap);
        }
```

I have added the following code from above **fillModel to **idDefault**** method as above.

```
if (configRepository.getDefault() != null
                    && configRepository.getDefault().getId().toString()
                            .equals(channelConfig.getId().toString())) {
                defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, Boolean.TRUE);
            } else {
                defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
```

I have the **isDefault** method which returns boolean values  as below

```
private boolean isDefault(final List<FacebookChannelConfig> config) {
        if (configRepository.getDefault() != null
                && configRepository.getDefault().getId().toString()
                        .equals(config.get(0).toString())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The above method **isDefault** is being used inside **fillModel method** as below

```
   protected void fillModel(final Model model,
                final List<FacebookChannelConfig> items) {
            final Map<FacebookChannelConfig, Boolean> defaultConfigMap = Maps
                    .newHashMapWithExpectedSize(items.size());
            for (FacebookChannelConfig channelConfig : items) {
              defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, isDefault(items));
             if (channelConfig.getOwner().getId().getId() != userContext.getOrganization().getId().getId()) {
                    channelConfig.setName(
                            channelConfig.getName() + "("
                                    + channelConfig.getOwner().getName()
                                    + ")");
                }
            }
            model.addAttribute("isDefault", defaultConfigMap);
        }
```

The above usage of **defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, isDefault(items));** is not correct.
Pleas suggest

Comment: i suggest moving this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use List where you wanted the element:
Maybe this could work:

```
    private boolean isDefault(final FacebookChannelConfig channelConfig) {
        if (configRepository.getDefault() != null
                    && configRepository.getDefault().getId().toString()
                            .equals(channelConfig.getId().toString())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and use:

```
defaultConfigMap.put(channelConfig, isDefault(channelConfig));
```